# PHP Syntax Challenge

Tags: php, powershell

I'm a Citrix admin, a journeyman PowerShell user, a beginner using PHP. I have though managed to create several PHP pages that run simple PowerShell commands as in this example:

**PHP snippet example showing how I successfully run POSH commands:**

```
<?php 
  $my_array = array(); 
  exec('powershell.exe -command "Get-XAAdministrator|Select -Property AdministratorName,AdministratorType" <NUL ', $my_array);
?>
```

However when I try to utilize a POSTED variable from a preceding HTML page that asked for a USER ID I can extract that variable just fine in the PHP page. I can echo and display it as JoeB for example on the resultant PHP page. But it needs to be entered into the PHP/PowerShell syntax encased in double quotes.

**Thus this PHP snippet does not work:**

```
<?php 
  $my_array = array();
  exec('powershell.exe -command "Get-XASession | Select -Property servername, accountname, logontime | where {$_.accountname -LIKE $ID}" <NUL ', $my_array);`
```

**This is how it would look and work in a normal powershell console:**

```
Get-XASession  | select -Property servername, accountname, logontime | where { $_.accountname -LIKE "JoeB" }
```

(Note that the USER ID JoeB is in double quotes.)

**Back to the PHP attempt to do this:**
- The variable $ID is the USER ID entered into the prior HTML form.

- It is being extracted from the HTML form as simply JoeB.
- And if it is entered into the HTML form as "JoeB" and extacted likewise it still does not work.
- The PHP/PowerShell command actually works, but it displays all XenApp Sessions as it is failing to properly read the value of $ID (accountname) and thus filter the results.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You should refrain from using so many caps. A few is alright, but if you want to emphasize something you can bold it.

Comment: Try this `{$_.accountname -LIKE '.$ID.'}"`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like the following:

```
<?php 
$my_array = array();
exec('powershell.exe -command "Get-XASession | Select -Property servername, accountname, logontime | where {$_.accountname -LIKE '.$ID.'}" <NUL ', $my_array);
```

The problem you are encountering, is that you cannot substitute a variable in **single quotes** as you have done there. It only works with double quotes. What I did, is end the string with a quote `'` and use a dot `.` which means "concatenate" and then $Id which is a variable (as a string from POST), and then concatenate again the rest of the string.

Good luck!

Comment: Appreciate the input.,but these suggestions do not work (they suggest the same thing.) 

It looks like the first single quote encountered in '.$ID.' terminates the powershell code as it is itself preceded with a single quote. That's my best guess, but in any event I am still unable to have the string from the POST properly read in yet, whether that string is domain\JoeB or "domain\JoeB" .